# How to parse the VTIMEZONE definition of an iCal to a nodatime type

Tags: c#, timezone, icalendar, nodatime

My application uses [ical.net](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) to process iCal appointments. In some cases I have to convert the appointment to the time zone of the participants. Since I currently use Nodatime for all date operations, I would like to convert the start and end date of the appointment into a `ZonedDateTime` object (or into another Nodatime type with which I can convert between time zones).

For this, I first have to convert the time zone embedded in the iCal into a Nodatime type.

**My question is:**
Can the time zone definition below be parsed into an equivalent Nodatime type so that I can convert the appointment to other time zones?

If so, what is the best way to do it? I can't imagine being the first to have this problem.

If not, is there any other way to implement my process? Or am I completely on the wrong track and have to think of another implementation?

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

### Update

For the sake of completeness, here is the entire iCal file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam\, Berlin\, Bern\, Rome\, Stockholm\, Vienna
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN="John Doe":MAILTO:john@doe.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Jane Doe
 :MAILTO:jane@doe.com
DESCRIPTION:Description
UID:ical-uid
SUMMARY:Summary
DTSTART;TZID="(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna":2
 0210427T100000
DTEND;TZID="(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna":202
 10427T110000
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20210419T125618Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:2
LOCATION:Location
BEGIN:VALARM
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: You've got a display name in TZID instead of an actual Windows or IANA time zone identifier.  iCal won't care, but others might.  Are you generating that?  The display name should be in a TZNAME field if you want it.

Comment: To be clear, you probably could create a `DateTimeZone` object from the `VTIMEZONE` alone, but it would only be valid for the periods defined.  It would be much easier if the `TZID` was one that you could look up from one of NodaTime's built-in `DateTimeZoneProviders`.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint No, I don't create the iCals. The are generated by Outlook, Google calendar, ... The example above is from Microsoft Exchange Server 2010.
If the TZID is a Windows or IANA time zone identifier I already look them up in the NodaTime `DateTimeZoneProvider`. But there are numerous iCal appointments with "invalid" TZIDs so I'm working on a fallback process that uses the VTIMEZONE definition of the iCal.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I only need the `DateTimeZone` object for the current iCal import. So it is ok if it is only valid for the periods defined in VTIMEZONE. But unfortunately I don't know how to do it. I have already seen that there is a min and max offset in the constructor, but how do I get the limits for standard and daylight saving time into the `DateTimeZone` object?

Comment: "I can't imagine being the first to have this problem." - I don't remember any feature requests for this coming in before, to be honest. (It's entirely possible that others have wanted to do it, but not reached out, of course.) It's not something we make simple - most of the classes used for time zone implementations are (very deliberately) internal.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your answer. Does that mean that what I plan to do with Nodatime cannot be implemented at all because the necessary classes are internal? Or does it mean that it is possible, but difficult to implement.

Comment: @onestarblack: It's possible, but difficult. You'd basically be reimplementing a bunch of the work in https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/TimeZones/StandardDaylightAlternatingMap.cs and https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/TimeZones/ZoneRecurrence.cs (etc). I wouldn't object to baking something into NodaTime itself to handle this (which would avoid a lot of the duplication) but I wouldn't expect that to come to fruition *quickly*.

Comment: @JonSkeet If Nodatime would support something like that in the future, it would be great (at least for me) :) Maybe it would also be useful for other developers. Time doesn't matter. I already have something that works for the most part and I need the Nodatime functionality for optimizations in order to be able to process "invalid" time zones in iCal appointments better. But in the end I leave it up to you whether you want to add this functionality to the Nodatime Library :) If you find it useful, I would of course appreciate it very much.

Comment: What does the rest of the ical look like?  If you're only concerned about the appointment times, then you primarily need the date, time, and offset of that appointment, not necessarily the whole time zone information.  It *helps* to have an actual time zone ID, in case the government changes the rules before the appointment comes into effect, but other than that scenario a simple offset (or UTC timestamp) will suffice.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Basically you're right, I just need the current offset. To find this out, I first have to calculate the limits for summer and winter time for the current year. Depending on the period in which the appointment is, the offset in this case is +1 or +2 hours. I was probably naive and thought there might be an *easy* way to do this. But it looks quite complex no matter how I do it.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/1634 for this.